# Künneth theorem for G-space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a right $G$-space and a left $G$ space, respectively, where $G=H \rtimes K$, $H$ a finite group and $K$ a compact Lie group.
Moreover, suppose that the $G$-action on $X$ is free. 
Denote $H_*(-)$ the singular homology with coefficient in a field.

Is $H_*(X \times_G Y )$ isomorphic to $H_*(X) \otimes_{H_*(G)} H_*(Y)$?

Is it possible to prove it without using spectral sequences?

Comment: [Crossposted on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3501863/39599).

Answer (score 13):

This is very untrue. Taking $X=EG$, a contractible space with a free $G$-action, and $Y$ to be a point we have $H_*(X\times_G Y)=H_*(BG)$, which may be non-trivial in arbitrarily high degrees, while $H_*(X)\otimes_{H_*(G)} H_*(Y)$ is the homology of a point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What hypotheses could I add to get the result? And what if it is not true? In this case, what can I say about $H_*(X \times_G Y) $

Comment: The standard way to be compute $H_*(X\times_G Y)$ when $G$ acts freely on $X$ would be to use the Serre spectral sequence of the projection $X\times_G Y\to X/G$, which is a fibre bundle with fibre $Y$ (at least when $G$ is compact). I know you said you wanted to avoid this, but in some cases (such as when $X=EG$ and you know how $G$ acts on $H_*(Y)$, as in my answer) the computations can be quite tractable.

Comment: @user740379 There is one case that's simpler. If $H_\ast(X)$ or $H_\ast(Y)$ are free over $H_\ast(G)$, you do get the result desired. In addition to the useful bundle-theoretic technique Mark Grant mentions, there is also something called the Rothenberg-Steenrod spectral sequence for calculating $H_*(X \times_G Y)$, specifically measuring the deviation in terms of Tor groups. (Sorry, I know that's less useful because you've specifically asked to avoid spectral sequence techniques.)